# "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.", but "hasrows" is true

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I wonder if anyone can shed any light on why I'm not getting data in this piece of code:

```
Private Sub RecoverUnsentOrderToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RecoverUnsentOrderToolStripMenuItem.Click
        ' Find orders for this branch with status = "1" - created but not acked from the server

        Dim myxDBReader As SqlDataReader
        Dim myxDBcmd As SqlCommand
        Dim query As String

        query = "select * from orders where branch = @branch and status = 1;"
        myxDBCmd = New SqlCommand(query, myDBCnn)
        myxDBcmd.Parameters.Add("@branch", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = BranchCode
        myxDBReader = myDBCmd.ExecuteReader
        If myxDBReader.HasRows Then
            Do While myxDBReader.Read
                Stop
            Loop
        End If
```

`BranchCode` and my database connection are public variables. When I run this code, it gets as far as the "Stop" and stops, but when I try to use the results, for example in the immediate window by trying to `? myxdbreader(0).tostring`, I'm getting "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present" exceptions. When I hover over `myxdbreader` to view the results, I get a list of the rows, but cannot see the data in them.

This is inside a reasonably large (for me, but not massive) VB application which executes all manner of queries and retrieves data without any problems. The code is copied and pasted from another section of the code where it works quite well. The database connection is a single one, opened when the application is started and passed around as required. Another part of the application writes into this "orders" table without any problem, using the same database connection.

I have another toolstripmenu function which is identical in every respect except the query, in this case it is simply

```
select * from linkstatus where id=1
```

and that has the same issue - stops inside the `do while dbreader.read` loop so it has obviously found a row, but will not allow me to access the data in the way that I normally do.

Because it gets to the "Stop", I know that `HasRows` is indeed true, and it appears to have read the first row. The only thing I can see that is different is that this code is run from a Menu that I added to the form today, whereas all the rest of the code is run from a variety of buttons on the main form.

Everywhere I've looked up that error message, it appears to be because people have not executed "Read".

This is vb.net from Visual Studio 2019, accessing SQL Server 2018.

Comment: Data readers are forward only. The moment you hover over it to see that there are rows, the enumeration is done and it's no longer usable. Depending on what your debugger does (like automatically evaluate locals without prompting) it may in fact be impossible to see rows that way. If you assign the column in the code first, then break and inspect that value, you should see it. Also, I would be remiss if I didn't mention Dapper as an alternative to writing this kind of boilerplate code yourself, which will also avoid issues with eager enumeration.

Comment: Normally when I write code like this, in the debugging stage I can hover over the data reader and view the results, then I'd stop debugging and do whatever I was planning to do with those results. If I remove the "stop" and instead debug.print some of the results, I'm getting data into the debug window. But, it's not the correct data, and it won't allow me to print fields by name, only by numeric index. The data it is displaying  appears to be actually displaying from the invoices table, which is most confusing as the function that lists invoices calls close() and dispose().

Comment: *"The database connection is a single one, opened when the application is started and passed around as required"*. Don't do that. That's not how ADO.NET is designed to be used. Create the connection where you create the command. Open the connection, get your data, close the connection and discard it. That's how the designers intended ADO.NET to be used.

Comment: One big red flag in this code (not sure if there's any relation to what you see but still) is that `myDBCnn` is not declared and created in the method itself -- reusing connection objects is a bad idea, since error handling becomes a massive pain. It's not necessary either; connections are pooled and connection objects are just transient handles to physical connections, so it's perfectly OK to create a separate connection (and dispose it) in every method that needs one (of course you can use a helper method/factory if you don't want to share the connection string or have other setup).

Comment: If you want to test the results of a data reader in a random-access manner, create a `DataTable` and call its `Load` method, passing your data reader. That will populate the `DataTable` with the data and then you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: OK, thanks for that - it sounds as if the shared connection may well be causing the problem, especially now I can see that it's actually retrieving data from another table entirely. I thought that using one would make things tidier and simpler, as I was thinking perhaps of there being an overhead in every connection. If it's a bad thing, I'll remove it.

Comment: There's no `IF`, it's just bad. Very bad. It goes against the design and the functionality of the ConnectionPool. It's not just about *violating the design*: as you have noticed, different procedures use the same object, possibly concurrently, with the consequences you're experiencing; it's also extremely bad for performance. Depending on the Provider in use, you can have the same query performed in the same network conditions that completes in tens of seconds instead of milliseconds. Data binding in an UI is one of such cases.

Comment: OK, got it. I'll make the change and it sounds as if that will cure my problem. I guess this is the consequence of me just blundering into this sort of code without reading up in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments by @jmcilhenny, @Jeroen Mostert and @Jimi the root cause of this was using a single public database connection. I have changed the code now so that it connects and disconnects to the database each time I need to access it using a private connection, and it now works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `Public` connection object, which as the comments state isn't the way to go. But most importantly, note that only one SqlDataReader can be associated with one SqlConnection, compounding the issue of a single shared connection.

[SqlDataReader.Read Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

> Only one SqlDataReader per associated SqlConnection may be open at a time, and any attempt to open another will fail until the first one is closed. Similarly, while the SqlDataReader is being used, the associated SqlConnection is busy serving it until you call Close.

It's probable that you already have an open Reader, and that is why you are seeing results for another data set.

Comment: I don't think I have an open reader connection - in my obsession with trying to make sure I don't leak memory, I do make sure that every one calls close() and dispose() after it's used, and when I saw that it was reading through the invoices table I did double-check that section of code. But I will remove the public connection and change it to open and close as required in each sub, and hopefully that will do the trick.